# Error when installing Flexget

Tags: python, pip

Having some problems trying to install flexget. I get the following error when I run the command:

```
pi@rpi:~$ sudo pip install flexget

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flexget in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking FeedParser>=5.1.3 (from flexget)
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement FeedParser>=5.1.3 (from flexget)
No distributions at all found for FeedParser>=5.1.3 (from flexget)
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Log:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 256, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1011, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 157, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for FeedParser>=5.1.3 (from flexget)
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try install feedparser manually with:

```
pip install feedparser
```

I also had to do this for functools32. In addition, running pip install flexget failed a couple of times before it managed to install it successfully.

Hope this helps.